# How to implement active/passive pattern with cloud services (web role)?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a web role doing some background processing in a background thread.

I want to run multiple instances of the web role, but I only want a single one of them processing the background jobs. If the designated instance running the background processing stops working for some reason, I want another instance to take its place.

What's the easiest way to implement this in Azure?

I thought about periodically checking the `Instances` collection of the `Role` object in `RoleEnvironment.Roles`, and run the background thread only if the current instance has the smallest Id (or decide with some other heuristics), thus only a single instance would process background jobs.
Should this approach work? Do role instances communicate heartbeat amongst each other, and does the `Instances` collection get updated accordingly?

Comment: Why not use a worker role for running your background tasks?

Comment: Yup, that would be the straightforward thing to do, however our client explicitly requested to have only a web role, so no additional instances would be needed because of the extra worker role.

Comment: How long are your background tasks going to be? Web role (hosting you background task in IIS) might be problematic - IIS can cancel the thread, app pool might be recycled etc. [See here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)

Comment: Couple of seconds or minutes each, so this probably won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [blob lease mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee691972.aspx) to control your instances.

All of your instances are trying to acquire a lock and the first one gets it. The rest is backing off and checking later. Processing instance can renew a lock. This way if your processing instance will fail (even hard fail) lease will be release after lease time pass and next instance can acquire a lock and start processing.

If you will rely on `Instance` with smallest Id you might end up in a situation where your instance is up and running but background processing thread is hanged/killed.

Have look [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases) and here [here](http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/?p=1371)

Update: 
[Leader Election Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568104.aspx)

Comment: I implemented this and it seems to work great. Thanks!

Comment: I know is a bit late since you have it implemented already, but patterns & practices described whole pattern [here - Leader Election Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568104.aspx)